# SQL Windowing Aggregation Over Two Consecutive Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not an SQL expert and finding this a bit challenging. Imagine I have the following table but with more users:

```
+---------+--------+--------+-------------+
| user_id | amount |  date  | sum_per_day |
+---------+--------+--------+-------------+
| user8   |   300  | 7/2/20 |     300     |
| user8   |   150  | 6/2/20 |     400     |
| user8   |   250  | 6/2/20 |     400     |
| user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |
| user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |
| user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |
| user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |
| user8   |   50   | 2/2/20 |     50      |
+---------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

As you see they are grouped by `user_id`. Now what I like to do is add a column called `sum_over_two_day` which satisfies the following conditions:

1. Grouped by `user_id`
2. For each user it is grouped by the `date`
3. The sum is then calculated per two consecutive calendar days for `amount` (today + previous calendar day)

So the output will be this:

```
    +---------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------+
    | user_id | amount |  date  | sum_per_day | sum_over_two_day |
    +---------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------+
    | user8   |   300  | 7/2/20 |     300     |       700        |
    | user8   |   150  | 6/2/20 |     400     |       500        |
    | user8   |   250  | 6/2/20 |     400     |       500        |
    | user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |       100        |
    | user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |       100        |
    | user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |       100        |
    | user8   |   25   | 5/2/20 |     100     |       100        |
    | user8   |   50   | 2/2/20 |     50      |       50         |
    +---------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to use a window function with a `RANGE` clause:

```
SELECT user_id,
       amount,
       date,
       sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                         ORDER BY date
                         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1 day' PRECEDING
                               AND CURRENT ROW)
          AS sum_over_two_day
FROM atable
ORDER BY user_id, date;

 user_id | amount |    date    | sum_over_two_day 
---------+--------+------------+------------------
 user8   |     50 | 2020-02-02 |               50
 user8   |     25 | 2020-02-05 |              100
 user8   |     25 | 2020-02-05 |              100
 user8   |     25 | 2020-02-05 |              100
 user8   |     25 | 2020-02-05 |              100
 user8   |    250 | 2020-02-06 |              500
 user8   |    150 | 2020-02-06 |              500
 user8   |    300 | 2020-02-07 |              700
(8 rows)
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Yes, your requirement is like designed to showcase the power of window functions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thank you so much for your reply. I am not so sure why I am getting a syntax error. It says only `syntax error at or near "INTERVAL"`. I am using dBeaver pointing to AWS Redshift. However, I believe ResShift supports the functions. Confused.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Thank you so much anyway for the solution. Being a newbe, I should have mentioned I am using Postgress which doesn't have this syntax. So instead of Interval I used Lag. However, I mark this as a solution.

Comment: Yes, you should have tagged Amazon Redshift. It is based on PostgreSQL, but is a closed-source fork, so probably based on an old version of PostgreSQL. Does it gag on the `INTERVAL` or on the `RANGE`? Does it work with `'1 day'::interval`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this workaround for your problem:

```
select 
t1.user_id, 
t1.amount,
date(t1.date_),
(select sum(amount)  from tab where user_id=t1.user_id and date_=t1.date_ ),
(select sum(amount)  from tab where user_id=t1.user_id and date_ between t1.date_-1 and t1.date_ )  
from tab t1
```

with Window function for first sum

```
select 
t1.user_id, 
t1.amount,
date(t1.date_),
sum(t1.amount) over (partition by t1.user_id,t1.date_),
(select sum(amount)  from tab where user_id=t1.user_id and date_ between t1.date_-1 and t1.date_ )
from tab t1
```

[see DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4Gb1wKCHfRVzzZjS4TkUF/2)